# Cant get text of a DropDownList in code - can get value but not text

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am using ASP.NET 3.5

I have a drop-down list called lstCountry with an item in it like this:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="United States">Canada</asp:ListItem>
```

This will display Canada but in code the value will be "United States". How can I retrieve the value "Canada" also in my code?

I have tried all of these and all of them return "United States"

```
lstCountry.Text
lstCountry.SelectedValue
lstCountry.SelectedItem.Text
```

My Drop Down list:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCountry" runat="server" Width="200px">
              <asp:ListItem>Please Select</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="United States">Canada</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

How I read the value in code:

```
    Dim country As String
    country = lstCountry.SelectedItem.Text
```

Comment: send u reply in email. check.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

add list using

```
<asp:ListItem Value="United States" Text="Canada"></asp:ListItem>
```

and then try

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
```

I found your mistake.

```
<asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
```

change this to

```
<asp:ListItem>United States1</asp:ListItem>
```

Then you will got the actual value.

What was the issue is, there are two same values in your dropdown, when page postback, it take first value as selected and give the result accordingly. if you noticed when after postback United State Value is selected

Comment: Nope, this is also returning the value "United States"

Comment: then there must be some other issue in your dropdown

Comment: are you setting selectedIndex=1 somewhere?

Comment: Nope it is not that, I have ALOT more items in my list. If i select one down below where the text and value is the same it is not returning United States.

Answer (score 3):

`AppendDataBoundItems="true"` needs to be set.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
lstCountry.Items[lstCountry.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Comment: Nope, this is also returning the value "United States"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
lstCountry.SelectedItem.Text
```

Comment: Nope, this is also returning the value "United States"

Comment: please provide more code please, I guess you are doing something wrong in other places

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
lstCountry.SelectedItem.Text
```

Comment: Nope, this is also returning the value "United States"

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem and just solved it, i used string [variable_Name] =dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here, this has a proof-of-concept page and demo you can use to get anything from the drop-down:  [asp:DropDownList Control Tutorial Page](http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/aspnet20/ASPNET06/aspnet06-06.aspx)